# VBA SELECT INTO / POSTGRESQL Sessions

Tags: vba, postgresql, ms-access

I have a postgresql database on a remote server and connect to it with an MS ACCESS frontend. What I do is create temporary tables on the client machines for speed, to avoid constant connection with the server.

I used PGADMIN and noticed an excessive amount of sessions on that remote database.
I'm using a lot of sql commands like:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT * INTO tempCustomers FROM customers;
```

To insert data into the temporary tables. Each of which creates a new session.

There are 7 clients, and about 12 tables, all create extra sessions, which make the computer running the database run slower, and when the limit of sessions is reached the application crashes.

Is there a way to close that Select recordset (like using rs.Close) to also close those Postgresql sessions?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the *CurrentDb* object:

```vb
Dim Sql As String

Sql = "SELECT * INTO tempCustomers FROM customers;"
CurrentDb.Execute Sql
```

Comment: Same issue with CurrenDb.Execute, the sessions aren't ending.